# Titanium, Wait for HTTPClient reply

Tags: android, titanium, httpclient

I'm using Titanium SDK to develop a small Android app that interacts with remote PHP files to retrieve its data.
The FOR loop executes before any data is returned by the HTTPClient, therefore 'myTest' is empty and nothing is added to 'tblListing'.

```
function jsonPOST( inAction, inParams ) { // jsonPOST is a global function
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e) {
            Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
            return this.responseText;
        },
        onerror : function(e) {
            Ti.API.debug(e.error);
            alert('error');
            return false;
        },
        timeout : 8000,  // in milliseconds
    });

    var sendData = {
        'action' : inAction,
        'json' : JSON.stringify(inParams)
    };

    xhr.open('POST', "http://domain.com/file.php"); // url redacted
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send( sendData );
} // end. jsonPOST()

var myTest = jsonPOST('getlisting'); // only need to pass first param in this instance
for (i in myTest) {
    tblListing.appendRow({ title: myTest[i].title, id: myTest[i].id });
}
```

Without delaying the execution of anything else on the same thread, how can I make the FOR loop wait til data is returned by the HTTPClient? The 'jsonPOST' function is used to retrieve various data for multiple elements in the app and should remain dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a callback parameter to allow a function to be called once data is received by HTTPClient. This allows the jsonPOST function to remain dynamic.

```
    function jsonPOST(inAction, inParams, inCallback) {

        var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
            onload : function(e) {
                Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
                var reply = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                inCallback(reply);
            },
            onerror : function(e) {
                Ti.API.debug(e.error);
                alert('error');

                return false;
            },
            timeout : 8000,  // in milliseconds
        });

        var sendData = {
            'action' : inAction,
            'json' : JSON.stringify(inParams)
        };
        xhr.open('POST', "http://domain.com/file.php"); // url redacted
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send(sendData);
    }

function processListing(inJson) {
    for (i in inJson) {
        tblListing.appendRow({
            title : inJson[i].listingTitle,
            id : inJson[i].listingID
        });
    }
}

jsonPOST('getListing', null, processListing);
```

Answer (score 0):

the loop needs to be in the function that is bound to the `onload` property of the xhr object:

```
 function jsonPOST( inAction, inParams ) { // jsonPOST is a global function
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e) {
            Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
            for (i in this.responseText) {
              tblListing.appendRow({ title: myTest[i].title, id: myTest[i].id });
            }
            return this.responseText;
        },
        onerror : function(e) {
            Ti.API.debug(e.error);
            alert('error');
            return false;
        },
        timeout : 8000,  // in milliseconds
    });

    var sendData = {
        'action' : inAction,
        'json' : JSON.stringify(inParams)
    };

    xhr.open('POST', "http://domain.com/file.php"); // url redacted
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send( sendData );
} // end. jsonPOST()

var myTest = jsonPOST('getlisting'); // only need to pass first param in this instance
```

Note that the HTTPClient works ansynchronous. It sends the request and waits for data, but in the meantime the calling script continues to execute.